# Multiple connections across different exit nodes in Orchid

Tags: exit-relays, java, orchid

I have an application using orchid where I need to have multiple connections, all using different exit nodes, to a server.

Is this possible using Orchid, and if it is, how would I do it?

Orchid doesn't have **any** documentation, so sorry if this is a basic question.